# function gets file path but i have a string with the file content

Tags: c#

I have a string with file content .
But my function deals with file path on the disc .
Any idea how i can solve this problem without writing to the disc my file content ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, overload your function so that it also takes filecontent as a parameter also?

If you can't alter the function and there is no other way, if it needs performance. Create a ram disk to write and read the file from.

Answer (score 0):

What is "your function" is it function you wrote?
If it is - make it to deal with Stream and then the one that deals file name open a stream and call the new one.

Comment: Usually libraries with function that takes a file path also provides and overload that takes stream. Check if such overload exists.